# Font not working in javafx css

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts, javafx-8

i formatted my laptop and installed netbeans for javafx. In my javafx project i cant load font form css.

before formatting laptop css custom font working very well.

i checked font path, it's right path.
i also tried set font from current directory.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Roboto';
src: url('/../Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}

.logoutButton{
-fx-background-color: #3498db;
-fx-font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
-fx-font-size:16;
-fx-text-fill: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely that `/..` is a correct path.  A URL is not a file name.  Your UR should be relative to the root of your classpath, not relative to your source directory.  Consider editing your question and showing the location of the `Roboto` directory in your project tree.

Comment: i tried from current directory but it's not working `.text{
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto";
    -fx-font-size:14; 
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}`

Comment: I repeat:  The URL in the `src` property has nothing to do with the current directory.  It is entirely based on your classpath, which is determined by your assembled project at runtime.

Comment: To help understand VGR's comments, see the description of [`<url>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl) in the JavaFX CSS reference guide.  See the examples in the linked guide on how urls are resolved, then ensure that the `Roboto-Medium.ttf` file is actually in the target classpath at the location determined.  If packaging as a `jar` (recommended), then run `jar tvf <yourjarfile>.jar` to see check the contents of the jar file and the location of the font and css files within the jar file.

Comment: thanks for reference guide..